i want to change the value of the first program with the second program
here is my problem
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int coins = 1;
    

    std::cout << &coins <<std::endl;

    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}

the coins value is the one i want to change with the second program
here is the code of the second program
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* coins = reinterpret_cast<int*> (0x57da7ffe7c);
    std::cout<<*coins<<"\n";
    return 0;
}

i expected that it will print the value of coins witch is (1) but it gives me this error (exited with code=3221225477)
the editor i use is vs code

Each process has its own address space. Even if the address 0x57da7ffe7c is a fixed one in one process, you cannot access it from another like this.

Where did you get that memory address from??

3221225477 --> This is 0xC0000005 which is an Access Violation.  Not sure where or how you expected a totally separate program with its own address space, plus has been terminated is supposed to magically retain 0x57da7ffe7c as the address to another, totally separate program.  Imagine you ran program 1 on Monday, and program 2 on Friday -- did you expect the results to show 1 after 4 days of your computer running thousands of processes?

@πάνταῥεῖ I guess it is from the cout output of the first program (but of course it is not valid).

In order to read the memory of another process on Windows (under certain limitations), you can have a look at ReadProcessMemory.

If this was allowed freely by the OS, there is no point in writing secure and safe programs because another program will easily read confidential data handled by another. Hold that thought for a moment. The other program whose data will be read has to give permission don’t you think?

You would need to investigate shared memory.
It is an advanced topic. This post may give you
a practical start.

Or what happens if you ran program 1, got that address, turned off or shutdown your computer, turned it back on, and ran program 2?  What would you expect then?

A side note: both your programs just print something to the console and exit, so they live for a very short while. This means that even if you used something like ReadProcessMemory (mentioned above) you wouldn't  catch the process alive in time.

Perhaps most curious - both of these programs end almost immediately after they are started.  Perhaps you believe that your variable exists in computer memory even when the program is not running?  That address 0x57da7ffe7c is forever reserved to hold this one integer for a program you might be running?

ok now i understand thank you to any body that answered my question I'm just new to c++ and didn't know that

@yousefmohammed -- The issue is not really about knowing or not knowing C++.  Even if you just started programming in any language, you should make it common knowledge as to how processes work.  Even the simple examples that I mentioned of running those programs on different days, or turning on/off your computer should have been indications that those two programs will not work in the way you thought they would.

@PaulMcKenzie thank you for explaining it to me , now i see the problem with my code

Your problem has nothing to do with C++ specifically, what you are trying to do is mostly consider malicious : viruses/hacks/cheats are developed this way. And operating systems have many many layers of defense to make this hard if not impossible. So even if you could get access to some valuable information at that address this time, the OS might randomize the memory layout the next time the code runs and evrything breaks down again. So don't waste your (and our) time on this.

Summary of information from the comments:

Each process has its own address space. Even if the address 0x57da7ffe7c is a fixed one in one process, you cannot access it from another process this way.

The error code; 3221225477, which you got (which is 0xC0000005 in hex) is "Access Violation", meaning that you attempted to read an invalid address.

You seem to be using Windows. There is a Windows API for reading another process’s memory (under certain limitations): ReadProcessMemory. You can have a look at the documentation link, but it's quite advanced to use.

The address space of a process is valid only as long as it is alive. Therefore if you use ReadProcessMemory, the first program would need to be still running at that stage (before your edit to the question you didn't have a Sleep in the first program, and so it would have exited almost immediatly).


